# How to make a switched outlet, half switched, half hot

Tags: wiring

In my garage I have an outlet in the ceiling that is fully controlled by a single switch due to a shop light being plugged into it. I would like to make half of that outlet always hot, so I can power the garage door opener.

Answer (score 1):

You want to break the connecting tabs off the receptacle (bend back and forth with needle nose pliers until metal fatigue causes them to break off), then just wire one plug to always be hot, and feed the other one through a switch:

[image]

Comment: +1 But unless you are powering the two outlets from separate circuits, there is no need to break the tab off the neutral side

Comment: @bib Well, right, you can leave the tab connected on the neutral side and let both outlets share the neutral through the outlet. Just be sure you switch the hot leg, which you really should be doing anyway.